# Jmeter Stuck after adding the asynchronous timer

Tags: jmeter

[image: 1]

When I add the asynchronous timer, it gets stuck. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not connected with the "asynchronous timer" (whatever it means), it's classic [OutOfMemoryError exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html)

The reason is that JVM asks the underlying operating system to create a new native thread and the process fails somewhere somehow, the reasons could be in:

- Java process doesn't have sufficient address space
- The underlying OS lacks virtual memory
- There is a limitation on the underlying OS level which doesn't allow that many native threads, i.e. [/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max](https://sysctl-explorer.net/kernel/threadsmax/)

So you either need to amend your JVM/OS configuration or will have to allocate another machine and switch to [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

More information: [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Unable to create new native thread](https://plumbr.io/outofmemoryerror/unable-to-create-new-native-thread)